# I flagged a comment but I have not heard anything back. What should I do?

Tags: support, flagging

I flagged a comment but I have not heard anything back. The comment was very strange and I want to know what is the reason for it. What should I do?

Also it came at the same time as what seemed like the unjustified closing of one of my questions from a month ago or so.

Comment: Did you check your flag history?

Comment: @ArcticChar How do I check my flag history?

Answer (score 3):

Don't flag comments if you expect a response.

The only response we, the moderators, can give to a comment flag is either delete the comment or decline the flag (we can decline & delete, obviously).

#### If you expect any kind of answer flag the post itself.

The flag you raised was marked helpful and the comment was deleted. That's all we can do with a comment flag.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that. How long should I wait before concluding that that also has not worked, and what would be the next step in that case?

Comment: You can see if the flag was handled and how at https://math.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/895582 (only you and the moderators can see this page).